# Java jogl applet paint not working?

Tags: java, opengl, applet, jogl

My jogl applet screen is blank. I have this for my paint code:

```
 public void paint(Graphics g){
        canvas.update(g);
    }
```

if I add g.fillRect(0,0,50,50); to it it'll draw the filled rect, but still not the jogl stuff.

Comment: What is 'canvas'? And what does "update()" do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear what the rest of your program looks like. However you should be aware that JOGL components don't draw like other components; in other words if this code is on an instance of GLAutoDrawable (i.e. GLJPanel or GLCanvas) then it won't do anything useful.

What you need to do is create a GLEventListener and attach it to the GLAutoDrawable. Then you need to implement `display (GLDrawable drawable)` with code that draws your 3D scene.

[This tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/09/11/jogl2d.html) is useful in getting you started.